# How to determine if a Set contains an object without reference (added on the fly to the set) in Javascript (ECMAScript 6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Well, `ECMAScript 6` Set allows adding objects into sets.

Like

```
var s = new Set();
var o = {a: 1, b: 2};

s.add(o);
s.add("c");
```

Determining if a "scalar" element (like c) is present is straightforward:

```
s.has("c"); // true
```

What about the same but for object elements ? I would think providing has() with the object's `toString()` value would return true, but it does not

```
o.toString() // -> "[object Object]"
s.has("[object Object]") // -> false
```

If Sets can contain objects, then its `has()` must know to determine whether a given object is contained. But how ?

**Update**: Although the solution to the **scenario depicted above** is just as well straightfoward (`s.has(o)`), what about adding an object on the fly to s, to which you do not have a reference ? In such a case, can you still determine if `s` contains that object ?

Comment: Why would the `toString()`-value be used? `s.has(o); // => true`

Comment: Obviously the `s` object does not contain the string `[object Object]`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the object directly, no fluff:

```
s.has(o);
```

This will return true.

This works, because the `s` Set holds a reference to the `o` object, so it the has function simply has to check that the reference of the object passed in, is held by the set.

**Object without "lost" reference**

If you add an object literal like

```
var s = new Set();
s.add({a: 1, b: 2});
console.log(s.has({a: 1, b: 2}));
```

This results in `false`, as the two objects have the same content, but they are different objects altogether. If you would like to test, that the set contains an object, with specific content, then you have to write your own code for that. The simplest algorithm would be:

- iterate through all elements in the set

  - if the contents are the same → `return true`
- if we did not return → `return false`

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) could have spared us my question if it added an example with a nested object...

Comment: @Veverke: Well, I guess it's pretty much covered in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Value_equality

Comment: I type faster than I think (and read) (which is definitely not complimentary to me)...

Comment: Wait a minute... the question actually raised due the following scenario: when you add an object on the fly to a set, not an object reference, like `s.add({a: 1, b: 2})` .

Comment: @Veverke: You are still passing a reference to an object. The only difference is that you are not storing the reference anywhere else. All objects are passed around as references, it doesn't matter how they are created.